# Set the value of a nested radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have many list of radio button in a ng-repeat.
I've succeded for get the selected item.
Now I try to set the default value of the radio.
Can some one help me please. Here my code for the button.
Thank's

```js
VariableRadioArr2 = [{"id":"21","libelle":"P15m","type":"radio","valeur_1":"Oui","valeur_2":"Non","valeur_3":"","valeur_4":"","valeur_5":"","valeur_6":"","valeur_7":"","valeur_8":"","valeur_9":"","valeur_10":""},{"id":"25","libelle":"Surface (m²)","type":"input","valeur_1":"","valeur_2":"","valeur_3":"","valeur_4":"","valeur_5":"","valeur_6":"","valeur_7":"","valeur_8":"","valeur_9":"","valeur_10":""},{"id":"36","libelle":"p16","type":"radio","valeur_1":"Oui","valeur_2":"Non","valeur_3":"","valeur_4":"","valeur_5":"","valeur_6":"","valeur_7":"","valeur_8":"","valeur_9":"","valeur_10":""}]

$scope.itemGroups = VariableRadioArr2;
console.log(VariableRadioArr2);
//$scope.selected = 1;
$scope.VariableRadioToggle2 = true;

$scope.clickedVariableRadio2 = function(test)
{
    $scope.clickedVariableRadio2_select = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.itemGroups));
}

if(VariableRadioArr2.length == 0) 
{
    $scope.clickedVariableRadio2_select = [];
    $scope.VariableRadioToggle2 = false;
}
```

```html
<ion-list id="page-list7" ng-show="VariableRadioToggle2">
   <div ng-repeat="itemGrp in itemGroups">
      <ion-item class="item-divider" id="page-list-item-divider32">{{itemGrp.name}}</ion-item>
      <ion-toggle name="{{itemGrp.name}}" ng-click="clickedVariableRadio2(portion.selected)" ng-repeat="(key,portion) in itemGrp.Portions" ng-model="itemGrp.selected_item" ng-true-value="'{{key}}'" ng-false-value="">{{portion.name}}</ion-toggle>
   </div>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: `itemGrp.selected_item` should be the default value.

Comment: Thank's for your quick answer. How can I do this ? I've tried ng-init="itemGrp.selected_item" in the ng-repeat div.                                       I've tried ng-init="itemGrp.selected_item" / ng-value="itemGrp.selected_item" / ng-checked="itemGrp.selected_item" in the ion-toggle div ... but anything work ? Is it thomething else to do in the controller part ?

Comment: Can you modify the `VariableRadioArr2` to have radio options as sub-array? `[{"id":"21","libelle":"P15m","type":"radio", "values": [{"value": "name",..}]},..]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm doing a loop from 1-10 to copy the values into a new object and delete the old ones.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var Variable = [{"id":"21","libelle":"P15m","type":"radio","valeur_1":"Oui","valeur_2":"Non","valeur_3":"","valeur_4":"","valeur_5":"","valeur_6":"","valeur_7":"","valeur_8":"","valeur_9":"","valeur_10":""},{"id":"25","libelle":"Surface (m²)","type":"input","valeur_1":"","valeur_2":"","valeur_3":"","valeur_4":"","valeur_5":"","valeur_6":"","valeur_7":"","valeur_8":"","valeur_9":"","valeur_10":""},{"id":"36","libelle":"p16","type":"radio","valeur_1":"Oui","valeur_2":"Non","valeur_3":"","valeur_4":"","valeur_5":"","valeur_6":"","valeur_7":"","valeur_8":"","valeur_9":"","valeur_10":""}];

  // Create sub object for all values 
  // and delete the old values
  for (i = 0; i < Variable.length; i++) {
      Variable[i].values = {};
      Variable[i].selected = '';

      for (v = 1; v < 11; v++) {
        if(Variable[i]['valeur_'+v] != undefined){
          Variable[i].values['valeur_'+v] = Variable[i]['valeur_'+v];
          delete Variable[i]['valeur_'+v];
        }
      }
  }
  
  $scope.itemGroups = Variable;
  
  // Set defaults
  // By index
  $scope.itemGroups[1].selected = 'valeur_4';

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="itemGrp in itemGroups">
    <div>{{itemGrp.libelle}}</div>
    <label ng-repeat="(key, value) in itemGrp.values">
      <input type="radio" name="{{itemGrp.id}}" ng-model="itemGrp.selected" ng-value="key">{{value}}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```